# Find next free value from a 5 char strings in database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a specific problem related to assigning item numbers to items in a shop.
Request is: Program should return next free value based on input.

Database contains 115k+ rows. Column 'sifra' which contains item numbers consists of 5 char VARCHARs.

VB.net application should have a single textbox in which user inputs up to 5 characters (all numbers).

Application logic should recommend user next free (unused in database) value.

Example:

Database contains values

```
00000
00001
00002
00003
00004
10012
10013
10010
01010
01011
01012
01013
```

If user inputs value `1` in textbox function should return `10000`

If he enters `0` return should be `00005`

If he enters `01` return should be `01000` and for `0101` return should be `01014`.

I have tried writing it as mysql procedure but i have only managed it to work with database column defined as `integer` and this is the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hiJGYtNhJAp72qH9RXVJc7/8). Note that everything except first query works as stated above in writen example.

Comment: Your numbering algorithm is not clear. Why does entering 1 return 10000 and not 10014 or 10011? What if all the numbers from 10000 to 10009 were used. What should it return then? Please add some more detail to your question...

Comment: Entering 1 returns 10000 because it is the next free number with 5 chars that starts with 1. You can see the Fiddle I linked. Running it should give you idea. The fiddle i linked works like a charm but it is made for Integers and calling the procedure with '0' breaks it. IF all numbers from 10000 to 10009 are used it should return 10010 of course. But only if user inputs '1' or '10' or '100' or '1001'. If user enters '1002' then function should return next free 5 char number that starts with '1002', so only numbers from '10020' to '10029' @Nick

Comment: Why not just use a regular autoincrementing pk, and stop worrying about the value? As it stands, what if a user enters 0000 and all values from 0-9 are taken?

Comment: @Strawberry Because that's how this shop works. Sometimes they use first 3 chars of string to identify a group of items and sometimes they identify whole department by first char in item number.In case they enter 0000 and 0-9 is taken function should return "FALSE" or NULL or whatever for all cases in which numbers are taken

Comment: IMO the vb.net application should handle this and not MySQL. It's way more easy to do this with VB code than in a stored procedure, it will cost you a few `LIKE` queries and `Strings.` functions.

Comment: @ThomasG How would i do this through VB.net?